# I need a shell script to response json 200 ok plus the body information

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to create a shell script that is in a CGI-BIN folder of an httpserver to return 200 ok plus the information I need to send back within the body

So I created a shell script "sendinfromation.cgi" and which is using the echo command to send the response

```
#!/bin/sh
info=$(ifconfig -a | grep -ioE '([a-z0-9]{2}:){5}..')

echo "statuscode : 200"
echo "body : $info"
```

I tried this as well

```
#!/bin/sh
info=$(ifconfig -a | grep -ioE '([a-z0-9]{2}:){5}..')
echo "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<HTML><body><blink>$info</blink></body></HTML>"
```

The response is not being sent in the right format and the client gets the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
```

How could I send the Json response?

Comment: You are trying to parse an HTTP response through a JSON parser...

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what actually runs the shell script for us to determine what it needs to output.

Comment: Since the error was produced by a JSON parser, perhaps `jq --arg x "$info" '{statuscode: 200, body: $x}'`?

Comment: @chepner you answer is really close, the only thing is that the body is coming as null

Comment: Ah, add the `-n` argument as well, so that `jq` isn't trying to read from standard input.

Comment: @jww - I think that fixing the formatting of this closed question might cause it to enter the reopen review queue - only it looks like it should be closed. Plus, the "Thanks for your advice" at the end should've been removed.

Comment: @Wai - Yeah, that's another usability bug that has never been fixed. Maybe Stack Overflow can hire another community manager to  sweep the problem under the rug rather than a developer to actually fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send output in a HTTP response, you should specify the content type. For HTML code for example you'll do something like this

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<title>Hello World</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'
echo 'Hello World'
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

From the error message I guess the client receiving your content is expecting it in json format, so it would become something like this

```
echo "Content-type: application/json"
echo ""
echo '{ "foo": 123, "bar": 456 }'
```